# Gap fill for a raster using another in R

Tags: r, image-processing, raster, fill, missing-data

I have two rasters for the same day but with different swaths. I want to combine them but I am conscious that retrieval algorithms may be different. Both rasters are of the same dimension. What's the easiest way to do this in R please? I will be running this on a list.

```
library(raster)

A <- raster(nrows=108, ncols=21, xmn=0, xmx=10)
A[] <- 1:ncell(A)
xy <- matrix(rnorm(ncell(A)),108,21)
B<- raster(xy)

##  Induce NAs in raster B:
B[sample(1:ncell(B), 1000)] <- NA

##  Confirm we have 1000 NAs:
sum(is.na(B[]))
```

If there were NA pixels in raster B that had values in the other raster A, how do I fill the raster B based on the correlation between points with values in both rasters A and B, please?

Comment: Do you mean you only want to replace a missing B pixel with A pixel if the local points of A are similar to the local points of B? Define local.

Comment: Hi @StephenHenderson. Yes. However, I want the fill to be based on the degree of agreement between areas with data in both rasters.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your rasters are of equal dimension and spatially coincident:

```
##  Create indices for pixels that are NA in B and not NA in A:
indices <- is.na(B)[] & !is.na(A)[]

B[indices] <- A[indices]
```

If they are not already of the same dimension and spatially coincident then use the `resample()` function first to match the rasters to the desired dimensions and extent (projecting first if necessary using `projectRaster()`).

Comment: Thanks @ForrestRStephens. Will this consider the correlation between pixels with data in both rasters?

Comment: Correlation? As in whether the pixels overlap each other?  It will if you've already resampled and/or stacked them to match the dimensions/extents... Please clarify if this isn't what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cover` as in

```
B <- cover(B, A)
```