# Fill pixel gaps in MYD13Q1 EVI with matching pixel from MOD13Q1 EVI raster in R

Tags: r, raster, r-raster, terra, r-modis

I'm working with monthly aggregates of MODIS EVI data from an area with a lot of cloud cover. Not many pixels are left after parsing for QA.

To improve the number of pixels, I want to combine pixels from `MYD13Q1.061 Aqua Vegetation Indices 16-Day Global 250m` with those from `MOD13Q1.061 Terra Vegetation Indices 16-Day Global 250m`. All images have been subjected to the same process in Google Earth Engine and importated in R. Sample files can me gotten [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZMjq9K67OsRQf90CI5pysZRk4TR9QHQ_/view?usp=sharing) (files are not large)

**MOD13Q1 EVI**

```
#Set working directory
setwd("C:/...sample/mod")

##load EVI tiffs
pathtif_evi='C:/...sample/mod/'
tiflist_evi=list.files(path = pathtif_evi,'*.tif')

##read in EVI tifs
all_tiffs_evi <- lapply(tiflist_evi, raster)
```

**MYD13Q1 EVI**

```
#Set working directory
setwd("C:/...sample/myd")

##load EVI tiffs
pathtif_myd='C:/...sample/myd/'
tiflist_myd=list.files(path = pathtif_myd,'*.tif')
```

I have tried a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35317334/10955882) from @Forrest R. Stevens using the code below it doesn't work on pixels. It seems suited for numeric values.

**Create indices for pixels that are NA in B and not NA in A**:

```
A <- all_tiffs_evi
B <- all_tiffs_myd
    
indices <- is.na(B)[] & !is.na(A)[]

B[indices] <- A[indices]
```

Please, I need help with a method for replacing NA pixels in one image with pixels from another (where a valid pixel exist). I have monthly data for 22 years. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `terra::cover` like this

```
library(terra)
fmod <- list.files(path="mod", pattern='tif$', full=TRUE)
mod <- rast(fmod)
fmyd <- list.files(path="myd", pattern='tif$', full=TRUE)
myd <- rast(fmyd)

x <- cover(mod, myd)
```

If there is no reason to prefer `mod` over `myd` then it could make more sense to take the mean values where they both have a value.

```
m <- mean(mod, myd, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: Perfect! Problem solved. I got a more complicated solution in GEE but this is very straightforward. Thank you.